# how to add css file in mpdf

Tags: php, html, ajax, mpdf

I am trying to convert html into pdf using mpdf. Problem is that i am unable to apply css to pdf file..

Here is my code of php:

```
<?php

    $html = $divPrint;
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf.css');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;

?>
```

What it is doing is taking html through ajax on my this php page. But the output it gives doesn't come with css which i've written for it..

Please tell me that to do now?

Comment: Have you tried `$stylesheet = '<style>'.file_get_contents('pdf.css').'</style>';`? I guess `pdf.css` contains only css so you have to _tell_ `html` that this is css.

Comment: it is working on local but not when i apply it at online server :(

Comment: did you make it work in the online server? I'm facing a similar problem

Comment: I find this library is easy to use as it supports HTML5 and css 3 because it is chrome based. https://github.com/spiritix/php-chrome-html2pdf

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
 <?php

$html = $divPrint;

include('mpdf.php'); // including mpdf.php
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('pdf.css'); // external css
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;

?>
```

1st assign your html in `$html` then include  **mpdf.php** file.

Comment: have one doubt. in my pdf 'padding' for 'li' tag is not working? Do we strictly need follow 'table' structure in pdf?

Comment: how can I add multiple css file?

Comment: @Mark you can add multiple css like this $stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/bootstrap.min.css');
        $stylesheet .= file_get_contents('css/AdminLTE.min.css');

Comment: i am using using https://packagist.org/packages/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf and i am unable to use inline css. like float, display, etc. What should i do?

Comment: if the css file is large like bootstrap it produces thousands of empty pages... :/