# HTML table to pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I have created an appliction for downloading a html table to pdf using javascript i used **[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)** plugin. The application is working fine but the problem is that the table is not proper. The width of the table as well as the header is not properly alligned. I am using angularjs for creating the table.

Can anyone please give me some suggestion for this problem

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00cvyyuo/)**

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    source = $('#customers')[0];
    specialElementHandlers = {
        '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
    margins = {
        top: 4,
        bottom: 4,
        left: 4,
        width: 522
    };
    pdf.fromHTML(
    source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top, { // y coord
        'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },

    function (dispose) {
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    }, margins);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280055/html-to-pdf-by-javascript-how-can-i-add-css-or-table

Comment: is that something to be  do with css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you currently have to do that manually ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00cvyyuo/1/)):

```
function demoFromHTML() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

    pdf.cellInitialize();
    pdf.setFontSize(10);
    $.each( $('#customers tr'), function (i, row){
        $.each( $(row).find("td, th"), function(j, cell){
            var txt = $(cell).text().trim() || " ";
            var width = (j==4) ? 40 : 70; //make 4th column smaller
            pdf.cell(10, 50, width, 30, txt, i);
        });
    });

    pdf.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
```

Comment: but why provider is seen out of the table

Comment: because "Customer Plan Provider" is longer than `70pt`. Here's a version that splits the words by spaces and puts newlines in instead: http://jsfiddle.net/00cvyyuo/2/

Comment: one more issue is that how to remove that empty row

Comment: the empty row is already in the HTML, you should remove it there.

Comment: since its been generated by angularjs thrid party plugin, i cant remove it.......can we do it from the javascript

Comment: It's probably best to reconfigure that plugin as it's also wrong to have the empty row in the HTML.

Comment: can we check while iterating whether all the columns within that row is empty or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62118/discussion-between-alex-man-and-mb21).

Comment: can we color and bold the header part

Comment: do you know how to add shim for IE9 [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103091/ie9-error-in-function-arraybuffer-is-undefined-referenceerror-arraybuffe?noredirect=1#comment40906866_26103091)

Answer (score 0):

try "jspdf" instead of "jsPDF"

Comment: that wont help.