# Try to add css in mpdf. But not accept anyhow

Tags: php, css, mpdf

I have tried to add css in `mpdfstyletables.css` file but can not able to add new css.
**PHP code:**

```
<?php

$html = utf8_decode($html);
$html = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
include("./MPDF/mpdf.php");
$tpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',32,25,27,25,16,13); 
$tpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstyletables.css');
$tpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$tpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$tpdf->Output($fname,'I');
exit();
?>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519335/how-to-add-css-file-in-mpdf) but not work for me.

How can I add css. I appreciate all response. Thanks Ahead.

Comment: What is in the css file? The code you posted should work correctly.

Comment: Wouldnt that fail because you are writing this to html without tags?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to render the html content instead of utf8_decode.

i.e,

```
 $tpdf->WriteHTML(("youtfilename.php")->render(),2);
```

By using like this I have applied two css files and it's working fine.

Hope it might help!