# Can i use inline css in mPdf while creating PDF?

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I already did this with external css.
but when i tried to do with inline CSS it wont work.

Can i use inline **css** in **mPdf** while creating PDF?
Guide me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add css file in mpdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519335/how-to-add-css-file-in-mpdf)

Comment: I know how to add css file in mpdf. but i didnt found it for inline CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [mPDF documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/user-s-guide/css-stylesheets/introduction.html), yes :

> The following are supported (in order of ascending priority - lower
>   ones in list overwrite higher):
>
> - HTML attributes e.g. `<div align="center">` (see supported HTML attributes)
> - CSS Stylesheets - included in header of HTML document or as `<link  />` or as `@import()`
>
>   - html tags e.g. `p { font-size:12pt; color:#880000; }`
>   - class e.g. `.stylename { font-size:9pt; }`
>   - id e.g. `#style { font-size:9pt; }`
> - **In-line CSS style e.g. `<p style="font-family:monospace;">`**

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

With mpdf,add the css with below

$styles = file_get_contents('style.css');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($styles,1);

Comment: This does not answer the question. He was asking for inline CSS.