# Loading external css files not working with MPDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, mpdf

I am using mPDF to generate pdf files from html. Now I also want to load some external CSS files and found in a couple of questions/answers on here that you are able to do that.

So I tried this:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents('../css/bootstrap.css');
$stylesheet .= file_get_contents('../css/custom.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$mpdf->Output($rootpad.'/uren.pdf','F');
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
[13-Nov-2019 10:56:05 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: html in /home/dropfaci/public_html/includes/pdf.php on line 47
```

When I remove some code and end up with the following code, a pdf is generated just fine but without css:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($rootpad.'/uren.pdf','F');
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: hmmm, have you defined html variable?

Comment: @RicardoCosta Yes Because without the stylesheets, the contents of `$html` are generated correctly into a PDF.

Comment: Can you take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/15567033/8233144 more code would be helpful to try understand what's happening

Comment: @RicardoCosta I have the same code as that answer except I save the file on my server.